# "tail -F" equivalent in lftp

Tags: lftp

I'm currently looking for tips to simulate a `tail -F` in lftp.
The goal is to monitor a log file the same way I could do with a proper ssh connection.

The closest command I found for now is `repeat cat logfile`.
It works but that not the best when my file is too big cause it displays each time all the file.

Answer (score 0):

The `lftp` program specifically will not support this, but if the server supports the extension, it is possible to pull only the last $x bytes from a file with, e.g. `curl --range` (see [this serverfault answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/18834/how-to-ftp-get-a-partial-file-only)). This, combined with some logic to only grab as many bytes as have been added since the last poll, could allow you to do this relatively efficiently. I doubt if there are any off-the-shelf FTP clients with this functionality, but someone else may know better.